# Any way deal with inter-variable?

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I am using R currently
But I think this question is universal

When you write the code in function oriented way, the code is very clear and each function realize one goal.

However if the function only output the goal result, you can't record some important inter-mid-result which may be an important clue for you to improve your code and/or find bugs

If you output both last result and important mid-result, that seems redundant and contradict to the one function one goal principle and make your code hard to read and hard to write.

Any one has any thoughts?

Comment: If you want both an intermediate result and an end result, is there a problem with returning a list with both?

Comment: You can use `print` to show the intermediate   result of your function, or use `<<-` rather than `<-` or `=` to assign variables in function to global.

Comment: I prefer to return lists, but if you want to go for *function realize one goal* then function should *return* before those intermediate results. And then have two more functions that would parse statistics of those results and pipe them further to analysis.

Comment: @PoGibas Hi what do you mean by return before intermediate results? After you return the function didn't calculate any longer

Comment: @JimChen That seems also a choice, I can add global var like function1_temp_result and using <<- inside the function

Comment: @duckmayr Yes I did it before but after a while I found it kind of waste of space because normally you will only use the final result, unless you want to improve your code or debugging and it is hard to read if you add too many mid results even for yourself after a while

Comment: @JimChen for printing I experienced benefits from printing plots, but it is really depends on the way you print(how much detail you want to show), if you choose a bad way print may be tedious and not helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is solved in LISP with multiple values : a function can return a value and auxiliary ones that can or not be used in the following computations.
In R you can return a list of results that indeed complicate your code or be inspired by the "regexpr" function that returns one value but actually two results :
the position as standard result, but having in an hiden attribute the length of the match.

```
> regexpr("ab","abc")
[1] 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 2
attr(,"index.type")
[1] "chars"
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
>
```

An example :

```
f <- function (x) {
  z <- x + 1
  attr(z,"aux")<- x-1
  return(z)
}

f(5)
```

Comment: It seems you are separating the result into main result and others, and using attributes property in R to realize your idea, good!